# Entity framework Context.SaveChanges not working at all

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-5

I'm having problems with this code. I´m able to connect to an mdf example database archive and generate the entity model. Althought I´m able to query the context model and retrieve information from the DB, when I try to update, delete or insert anything in the context and translate the changes to the DB Context.SaveChanges is not working. There is no Exception, the Entity model is updated properly, but the DB does not have the change.
Thanks in regard

```
public void addCourse(int courseId, int deptId, string courseTitle)
{    
SchoolContexto = new SchoolEntities();            

Course mycourse= new Course();
mycourse.CourseID = courseId;
mycourse.Credits = 10;
mycourse.DepartmentID = deptId;
mycourse.Title = courseTitle;
SchoolContexto.Courses.Add(mycourse);            

SchoolContexto.SaveChanges();
SchoolContexto.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem first time I used Entity Framework. In fact I was not watching the proper db. I had an old one and Entity Framework created another one. Not a response just to add information.

Comment: Ok, based in this I have found the problem!!!
When I created the connection to the database to generate the model, the VS offer you to include the .mdf in the solution and change the connectionstring. Don´t do that!!! its a boobytrap!! XD
When I tried again to generate the model, I choose not to include the DB in the solution and now everything works fine.
Thanks budies!!!

Answer (score 7):

Make property of .mdf file in your solution as 
Copy to output Directory: "Copy only if newer"

Otherwise your db file will overwrite every time it runs

Answer (score 2):

i suggest you to use this code :

```
public void addCourse(int courseId, int deptId, string courseTitle)
{    
     SchoolEntities entities = new SchoolEntities();            

     Course mycourse= new Course();
     mycourse.CourseID = courseId;
     mycourse.Credits = 10;
     mycourse.DepartmentID = deptId;
     mycourse.Title = courseTitle;
     entities.Courses.Add(mycourse);            

     entities.SaveChanges();

 }
```

if this is not working i suggest you to check your app.config file :)

Comment: Sorry, my fault on copying the code. Indeed the SchoolContexto  is declared early in the code (I'have have already try to define it in the function as you did, but doesn't work either. :(

Comment: This is my connection string
<add name="SchoolEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\School.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: and this is my EF factory
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add a new entity to the context is to change its state to Added. Have you tried this

```
using (var entities = new SchoolEntities()) 
{ 
    Course mycourse= new Course();
    mycourse.CourseID = courseId;
    mycourse.Credits = 10;
    mycourse.DepartmentID = deptId;
    mycourse.Title = courseTitle;
    context.Entry(mycourse).State = EntityState.Added;
    entities.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Comment: It doesn´t work either... this is freaking me out , jejeje.
I don´t understand where is the problem... it's just an example solution I'm building from a tutorial. I'd just created the proyect, the model, request entities from DB (this worked) and try this code. There is no more complex process in the solution. ainggg
Thank´s.

Comment: What does SaveChanges() return? It should return the number of objects added

Answer (score 0):

I think the Problem is that you working on localdb (.mdf) file .
I had the same problem but when i created new (sql server database connection)
Server name : (localdb)\MSSqlLocaldb .... it worked

Answer (score 0):

A little off the subject but just in case you're here because you're performing an update and not an add, Check if you need a key on the table. I had a similar issue with EF Core. During an update on a table no error was generated but the SaveChanges returned 0. It wasn't until I tested adding a record, that it generated the key error. I resolved the key issue and the update went fine.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because probably you don't have primary key in your `Course` entity.

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem by including the following namespace

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```